# undefined method `micropost_path' ROR Tutorial 3rd Edition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

Why do I get the following, "undefined method `micropost_path'" in StaticPagesController , error, even though I copied Hartl's code verbatim?

Below is some of the code.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root                'static_pages#home'
get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
resources :users
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :edit]
end
```

StaticPages Controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
def home
if logged_in?
  @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
  @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
end

def help
end

def about
end

def contact
end

end
```

MicropostsController

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy


def create
@micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
if @micropost.save
  flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
  redirect_to root_url
else
  @feed_items = []
  render 'static_pages/home'
end
end

def destroy
 @micropost.destroy
 flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
 redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
end


private

def micropost_params
 params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
end

def correct_user 
@micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
end

end
```

Two of the answers, on this website, to this issue were solved for other reasons.

For example writing

```
micropost
```

instead of

```
microposts
```

I don't have these grammatical errors here if I am not mistaken.. Any idea what other problem could be causing this?

P.S. Using cloud9 IDE while following tutorial.

Comment: In your routes you only define create and edit path for microposts. Micropost_path is usually the one for the show action/route like micropost_path(@micropost). If you want to check all your routes you can go to `http://localhost:3000/rails/info`.

Comment: Can you add the view code where the error comes from?

Comment: I guess that it is in the home action of StaticPagesController and the path inside the form is probably not good or the method isn't pass. You should have something like `form_for(@micropost)`?

Comment: thanks guys, I actually just made a silly error.. instead of     :edit it should be    :destroy

Comment: That makes sense, your routes files differs from your controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

In routes.rb I had the following resources for microposts

```
resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :edit]
```

Instead,it is supposed to be

```
resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
```

The

```
:destroy
```

was missing.

Found this out after running 'rake routes'..

got this route

```
edit_micropost GET    /microposts/:id/edit(.:format) microposts#edit
```

instead of

```
micropost DELETE /microposts/:id(.:format) microposts#destroy
```

This shows the routes with their corresponding actions that should be in the controller.